# How to prove combinatorical sum identity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

$$\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{2n+1-2k}\binom{2n+1-k}{k}(-1)^k=2(n+1)$$

According to wolfram, this is true. How would one prove this either algebraically or combinatorically?

Comment: More generally, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^m 2^{m-2k} \dbinom{m-k}{k} \left(-1\right)^k = m+1$ for all $m \geq -1$. (Your formula is the particular case when $n = 2m+1$, but notice that my sum has extra zero terms compared to yours.)

Comment: As for why it is true... More generally, if you fix a number $r$, and set $d_m = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m r^{m-2k} \dbinom{2m-k}{k} \left(-1\right)^k$ for all $m \geq -1$, then the sequence $\left(d_{-1}, d_0, d_1, \ldots\right)$ satisfies the recurrence $d_n = r d_{n-1} - d_{n-2}$ (check this!). Now the claim follows by an easy induction (with $r = 2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the *coefficient of* operator  $[z^n]$     to  denote  the coefficient  of  $z^n$  in  a  series. This  way  we   can  write for instance
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=[z^k](1+z)^n
\end{align*}

> We obtain for $n\geq 0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n}&\color{blue}{2^{2n+1-2k}\binom{2n+1-k}{k}(-1)^k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k+1}{n-k}2^{2k+1}(-1)^{n-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n[z^{n-k}](1+z)^{n+k+1}2^{2k+1}(-1)^{n-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=2(-1)^n[z^n](1+z)^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-4z(1+z))^k\tag{3}\\
> &=2(-1)^n[z^n]\frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{1+4z(1+z)}\tag{4}\\
> &=2(-1)^n[z^n]\frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{(1+2z)^2}\\
> &=2(-1)^n[z^n]\sum_{j=0}^\infty(j+1)(-2z)^j(1+z)^{n+1}\tag{5}\\
> &=2(-1)^n\sum_{j=0}^n(j+1)(-2)^j[z^{n-j}](1+z)^{n+1}\tag{6}\\
> &=2(-1)^n\sum_{j=0}^n(j+1)(-2)^j\binom{n+1}{n-j}\tag{7}\\
> &=2(-1)^n\sum_{j=0}^n(j+1)(-2)^j\binom{n+1}{j+1}\tag{8}\\
> &=2(-1)^n(n+1)\sum_{j=0}^n(-2)^j\binom{n}{j}\tag{9}\\
> &=2(-1)^n(n+1)(1-2)^n\tag{10}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2(n+1)}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we change the order of summation: $k\to n-k$.
- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$. We also set the upper limit of the series to $\infty$ without changing anything, since we are adding zeros only.
- In (4) we use the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (5) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (6) we apply the same rule as in (3) and restrict the upper bound of the series to $n$ since the powers of $z$ are non-negative.
- In (7) we select the coefficient of $z^{n-j}$.
- In (8) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (9) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (10) we apply the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)*.